# select data from sqlite in angular. Data is nor rendered

Tags: javascript, sqlite, angularjs, cordova

I'm building mobile application with phonegap and angular.js. I'm using SQLite to save local data. 
And my Problem is that I can't render asynchronous data which I'm getting from sqlite.
So the problem is that data is not rendered
I'have even tried $apply method but it doesn't works.

Here is my code below

```
function ProjectListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(){
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

        var test1 = function(db_result){
        //                $scope.projects = db_result;
        //                $scope.$apply();

            $scope.projects = db_result;
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.projects = db_result;
            });

            console.log($scope.projects)
        }
    var make_result = function (tx, results, $scope) {
        querySuccess(tx, results, $scope,test1 );
    };

    function querySuccess(tx, results, $scope, callback) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var db_result = [];
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            db_result[i] = results.rows.item(i);
        }
          callback(db_result)
        // $scope.projects = results.rows;
        // $scope.$apply(); //trigger digest
    };

    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Projects', [], make_result, errorCB);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Any update on this? I'm working with AppGyver Steroids which also works with AngularJS and i'm sitting on a SQLite db too...  any intel would be appreciated

Comment: I was looking for the same and found the answer here:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736214/trying-to-get-an-async-db-request-to-work-in-angular-cannot-call-method-then-o

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use $q service

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)